# Add image to flutter branch sdk package

Tags: flutter, image, sdk, package, branch

Is there a way to add an image from directory path or from the asset folder to the link that generated by branch sdk flutter package instead of Network Image link?

```
buo = BranchUniversalObject(
        canonicalIdentifier: 'flutter/branch',
        //parameter canonicalUrl
        //If your content lives both on the web and in the app, make sure you set its canonical URL
        // (i.e. the URL of this piece of content on the web) when building any BUO.
        // By doing so, we’ll attribute clicks on the links that you generate back to their original web page,
        // even if the user goes to the app instead of your website! This will help your SEO efforts.
        canonicalUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
        title: 'Flutter Branch Plugin',
        imageUrl:
            'https://flutter.dev/assets/flutter-lockup-4cb0ee072ab312e59784d9fbf4fb7ad42688a7fdaea1270ccf6bbf4f34b7e03f.svg',
        contentDescription: 'Flutter Branch Description',
        /*
        contentMetadata: BranchContentMetaData()
          ..addCustomMetadata('custom_string', 'abc')
          ..addCustomMetadata('custom_number', 12345)
          ..addCustomMetadata('custom_bool', true)
          ..addCustomMetadata('custom_list_number', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
          ..addCustomMetadata('custom_list_string', ['a', 'b', 'c']),
         */
        contentMetadata: metadata,
        keywords: ['Plugin', 'Branch', 'Flutter'],
        publiclyIndex: true,
        locallyIndex: true,
        expirationDateInMilliSec:
            DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 365)).millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

child:
Image(
image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
), //in the .dart file
//then

assets:

- assets/logo.png
  //in pubspec.yaml file

you can follow this link also:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images